# How do I change the source of an image via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

So, right now, I have this code, which has an upvote and downvote image (img/upvote.png and img/downvote.png) and when they are clicked, they should change source to img/orangeupvote.png, and downvote to orangedownvote.png (which are also both images in the img folder directory). So, for this I have this code:

```
<div style="position: fixed; margin-left: 1030px; margin-top: 235px">
    <img class="textupvote" id="textUpvoteImg" src="img/upvote.png" alt="upvote" onclick="changetextUpvote()" style="width: 100px; margin-bottom: 28px; cursor: pointer">
    <img class="textdownvote" id="textDownvoteImg" src="img/downvote.png" alt="downvote" onclick="changetextDownvote()" style="width: 120px; margin-top: -12px; position: fixed; cursor: pointer">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function changetextUpvote() {
  var textUpvoteImg = document.getElementById('textUpvoteImg');
  if (textUpvoteImg.src.match("orangedownvote")) {
    textUpvoteImg.src = "img/upvote.png";
  } else {
    textUpvoteImg.src = "img/orangedownvote.png";
  }
}

function changetextDownvote() {
  var textDownvoteImg = document.getElementById('textDownvoteImg');
  if (textDownvoteImg.src.match("orangeupvote")) {
    textDownvoteImg.src = "img/downvote.png";
  } else {
    textDownvoteImg.src = "img/orangeupvote.png";
  }
}

</script>
```

So, when I try this out on a different document, it's working. The upvote and downvote images are both successfully changing to the orange versions of them (orangeupvote.png and orangedownvote.png), on click. However, when I try this on my current document, it isn't working. I even inspected, and on click, it isn't changing source, but then for any other image (anything which isn't orangeupvote.png or orangedownvote.png) is working. If is specify any other image on click, it's working, but orangeupvote.png and orangedownvote.png aren't working.

EDIT:

When I click the upvote button, it shows both orange downvote and upvote at the same time. This shouldn't happen. It should only show orange downvote. (Actually orange upvote, but I'm doing this to test). Similarly, with the downvote button, when clicked it should show only orange upvote, but it shows orange upvote and downvote at the same time. Here's an image for more clarity:

Image on what's occurring:

[image]

Comment: I cant see any error in the js code, what do you mean with "another document" and "actual document"? what difference are between these two? try to debug with console.log() and check if the condition enters in the correct way.

Comment: This document has a lot of content, while the other one is empty. Secondly, if I try any other image besides orangeupvote.png or orangedownvote.png, it works perfectly fine. It changes source on click. However, if I try orangeupvote.png or orangedownvote.png, it doesn't work. Any other image changes source on click (can confirm using inspect), but orangeupvote.png or orangedownvote.png don't (doesn't change source in inspect either).

Comment: If you need help with what the Event-Handlers should do, please explain in more detail, which behavior you expect, when the user clicks on `img#textUpvoteImg` and `img#textDownvoteImg` respectively

Answer (score 0):

In order to write modern JavaScript you should define the Event-Listeners with addEventLisener:

Also, you should not pass a function call to `onclick` Attribute, but only the function reference, which should be executed on click.

Correct: `onclick="changetextUpvote"`

I'm not sure, whether the if-statements inside the Click-Handler do what they should..Maybe, I'd rather use `String.prototype.includes` instead of match (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

EDIT: Eventlisteners do not check the current img source. They just change the src to the desired image/png after click.

```js
<div style="position: fixed; margin-left: 1030px; margin-top: 235px">
    <img class="textupvote" id="textUpvoteImg" src="img/upvote.png" alt="upvote" style="width: 100px; margin-bottom: 28px; cursor: pointer">
    <img class="textdownvote" id="textDownvoteImg" src="img/downvote.png" alt="downvote" style="width: 120px; margin-top: -12px; position: fixed; cursor: pointer">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var textUpvoteImg = document.getElementById('textUpvoteImg');
  var textDownvoteImg = document.getElementById('textDownvoteImg');

function changetextUpvote() {
  // removed if-else statement here
  textUpvoteImg.src = "img/orangedownvote.png";
}

function changetextDownvote() {
  // removed if-else statement here
  textDownvoteImg.src = "img/orangeupvote.png";
}
  
// Only pass the function name, not the function call (e.g. not changetextUpvote())
textUpvoteImg.addEventListener('click', changetextUpvote);
textDownvoteImg.addEventListener('click', changetextDownvote);

</script>
```

Comment: Hey, this doesn't work, on neither document.

Comment: I edited my question so you can get more clarity about what's happening. I pasted an image.

Comment: I created this pen in order to verify that my example is changing the src to the files specified in the click handlers: https://codepen.io/ckozalla/pen/GRMNzzy (inspect, then check before and after click)

Comment: In inspect, the source changes, but the actual image (identified using the "alt"), doesn't change, which indicates why the image source may be changing in my example, but it isn't actually physically changing on the screen.

Comment: I really don't know, why both arrows are present at the same time as shown in the image of your updated/edited question. I feel the if-else-statement is obsolte, because I understand you want to change the picture on the first click. So you can simplify and leave out the if-else-statement

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please simplify, possibly with some code?